# Laravel 5.4 Route is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, url-routing

I am new in Laravel. I use Laravel 5.4.

My Route file is :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->name('users');
    });
});
```

When I use url in browser `admin/home` its working , but When I just use `admin/` it redirecting me to Welcome page.

simply it's not working when I use url http://appurl/admin/ but it is working when I use http://appurl/admin/home
When I am wrong ?

MY Home Controller ::

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

I noticed when I remove this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I will work for `http://appurl/admin/`

Comment: what's inside your `HomeController@index`  function ?

Comment: `public function index()
    {
        return view('admin/dashboard');
    }`

Comment: @SagarGautam in index function there is just showing view only

Comment: simply its not working when I use url `http://appurl/admin/` but it is working when I use `http://appurl/admin/home`.

Comment: Then, strange problem

Comment: Is there another route called `admin` in your `web.php` file. Are you sure ?

Comment: I posted my `web.php` all code. There is no other `admin` route.

Comment: I noticed when I remove `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});` It is working `http://appurl/admin/`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `/` before home.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->name('users');
    });
});
```

But I am little bit confused. Why you are calling same function `HomeController@index` twice.

Comment: @Minae Mnr till it is not working adding `/` before `home` :(

Comment: what's inside your `HomeController@index` function ? Did you notice you are calling that method twice both for `/` and `/home`.

Comment: I edit my Question and post my home controller code.

Comment: I noticed when I remove `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});` It will work `http://appurl/admin/`